# Tag <picture> não funciona em celulares e IE11

Tags: html, css

Estou a trabalhar com a tag `<picture>` para usar sua função responsiva e inserindo  diversos tamanhos da mesma imagem num único objeto conforme a resolução da tela pelo parametro "media" da tag `<source>`. No chrome e no Mozilla Firefox os resultados foram perfeitosm mas nos celulares e IE11 nao funcionou, estão apenas usando a imagem na tag `<img>` segue um exemplo do erro:

```css
a#capa-individual{
width: 85%;
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: 3%;
margin-bottom: 3%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 30px solid rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
.foto1{
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="erro.css">
</head>
<body>
  <a id="capa-individual" href="individual.html">
   <picture>
       <source class="foto1" srcset="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/lying-male-dalmatian-18553200.jpg" media="(max-width: 480px)">
       <source class="foto1" srcset="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/liver-spotted-dalmatian-bitch-17136208.jpg" media="(min-width:481px)">
       <img class="foto1" src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/liver-spotted-dalmatian-bitch-17136208.jpg.jpg" alt="">
   </picture>
  </a>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que não funcionou exatamente? Que erro deu, não reconheceu o CSS? Explique melhor.

Comment: Realmente não aparece erros amigos, tudo funciona, mas não do jeito certo, é muito estranho porque estou aqui a testar em varios dispositivos, e em nenhum celular a  função "media" da tag <picture> esta funcionando. A foto que aparece nos celulares abaixo de 480px é simplesmente a foto grande que esta na tag <img>. Mas por outro lado no chrome e no Mozilla é perfeitamente funcional, quando ponho o navegador para resolução abaixo de 480px, logo aparece a foto pequena. Já no IE quando ponho o navegar abaixo de 480px, continua a foto grande, nao reconhece o "media". Não sei o que esta acontecendo

Comment: Se é um problema com a mediaquery então você deve colocar o css todo, coloque algo que possamos reproduzir. Se você só coloca trechos e fala que o problema é em outro lugar fica difícil entender. Quando falo ERRO não quero dizer mensagem de ERRO e sim pra explicar como deveria funcionar e o que está acontecendo ao invés do esperado. Coloque um código que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Certo, então segue o CSS na integra e o Html da tag picture, ficou um pouco grande mas o erro pode estar em algum lugar no meio disto tudo, eu olhei e olhei e nao achei. Os editei na perguta. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: quando disse pra colocar um exemplo que possamos reproduzir, era pra você pegar as partes somente necessárias e tentar fazer o mesmo efeito de falha, ficou um CSS gigante que só você entende, recomendo mesmo que com toda atenção leia este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve assim fica mais fácil a você nos ajudar a ajuda-lo ;)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a5cb71 http://prntscr.com/a5cbaw

Comment: @guilherme, valeu pelas orientações, ja li o post e desculpa, agora entendi como fazer, segue ai o codigo com o erro, Executei no meu servidor e deu o memso erro de sempre , esta acontecendo o mesmo que no meu site. Chrome e mozila o codigo funciona perfeitamente e IE e celulares nao funcionam

Comment: @GOLX Só mais 2 coisas, quais celulares ocorrem o problema? No meu IE11 eu notei a falha, assim que tiver um tempo vou tentar entender o que ocorreu (estou em horário de trabalho) ;) - Ps.: Ficou ótimo o exemplo que adicionou e foi possivel entender a falha.

Comment: @RZ-8121 então esta é falha, era para no IE11 aparecer a primeira foto, as demais ele só mudou o nome, sei  que não ficou tão claro, mas assim que tiver um tempo vou editar, o problema dele é a tag `<source>` que não funciona então mostra a tag `<img>` que é um fallback, se você quiser pode tentar responder, eu sei o motivo disto, o problema é que ainda não tenho uma solução alternativa ;)

Comment: @guilherme, obrigado, então nao funciona nos 2 celulares que testei, Samsung Galaxy Duos e ZTE, os dois com tela menor que 480px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento `<picture>` não é suportado no Safari para iOS e no IE11.
É possível verificar isso em http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture.

Uma alternativa é o uso dos atributos `srcset` e `sizes`, onde é possível especificar diferentes imagens para diferentes resoluções. Segundo o *Can I use...*, o recurso já é amplamente suportado (http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset).

Exemplo:

```
<img src="small.png" 
     srcset="large.png 1280w, medium.png 640w, small.png 320w" 
     sizes="(max-width: 500px) 250px, 500px" 
     alt="">
```

No `srcset`, você especifica o endereço da imagem e logo após a largurda dela em pixels (`1280w`). No atributo `sizes`, é indicado ao browser os breakpoints usando uma media querie e o tamanho que a imagem será exibida.
O tamanho `(max-width: 500px) 250px, 500px` diz ao browser "se a `viewport` for menor que 500px, a imagem terá 250px de largura. Se maior, a imagem será exibida com 500px de largura. O browser vai escolher qual daquelas imagens melhor se encaixa a essa situação.

Comment: vi o Caniuse e realmente nao é o IE 11 nao suporta a tag, e pelo que vi browser do android tambem não. obrigado.
Voce tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer para apresentar substituir esta função?

Comment: Ótima resposta e muito boa alternativa. @GOLX se resolveu marque a resposta como correta.

Comment: sim a resposta do afonso matou o porque. E qual alternativa posso ter para este problema? seria fazer uma img com display:none com a foto menor. E telas menores que 480px (celulares), punha um display:block para a foto pequena e um display:nome para a foto grande? Será essa a melhor alternativa?

Comment: @GOLX na própria resposta já apresento uma solução para o problema. Algo mais rudimentar seria exatamente o que você falou: tratar com `display:none` e `display:block`. Mas isso faria o navegador carregar as duas imagens, o que deixaria o carregamento da página mais lento.

Answer (score 3):

O elemento `picture` não é suportado no IE11, você pode consultar quais navegadores suportam ele em: http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture.

O que você pode fazer para que o IE11 suporte ela é usar um polyfill, que são bibliotecas javascripts que simular o comportamento de novas funcionalidades em navegadores antigos:

Um polyfill para o picture poderia ser o : https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Adicione esse código a sua página para que o picture polyfill funcione:

```
<head>
  <script>
    // Picture element HTML5 shiv
    document.createElement( "picture" );
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/picturefill/3.0.2/picturefill.js" async></script>
</head>
```

Exemplo no Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMKqqz

Comment: Muito interessante a biblioteca +1