# Uso de tag picture

Tags: html, imagem, picture

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width:min-width:1440px)" srcset="img/main_banner_info-1440px+.png">
   <source media="(min-width:min-width:660px)" srcset="img/main_banner_info-660px~1439px.png">
    <img src="img/main_banner_info-320px~659px.png" alt="Informações: IdeaBag, central de ideias programadas">
</picture>
```

Porém, ao rodar no navegador, apenas o elemento `<img>` é exibido, não importando o tamanho da página, verifiquei as url's e estão todas corretas, porém, não funcionam, testei nas versões atuais do firefox e chrome. Por que este erro ocorre, e como posso corrigí-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você escreveu o conteúdo do atributo MEDIA duas vezes, isso confunde o funcionamento:

```
min-width:min-width:1440px
```

Correto:

```
min-width: 1440px
```

Acredito que o atributo MEDIA funcione igualmente CSS3, então segue o mesmo padrão pra entender páginas responsivas e a TAG IMG é caso nenhum deste possa ser carregado ou o navegador não suporte essa TAG.

**Observação sobre método alternativo:**

Fonte: [Tag  não funciona em celulares e IE11](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114075/tag-picture-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-celulares-e-ie11/114573#114573)

Se quiser usar mma alternativa é o uso dos atributos `srcset` e `sizes` direto na tag `img`, onde é possível especificar diferentes imagens para diferentes resoluções. Segundo o *Can I use...*, o recurso já é amplamente suportado (http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset).

Exemplo:

```
<img src="small.png" 
     srcset="large.png 1280w, medium.png 640w, small.png 320w" 
     sizes="(max-width: 500px) 250px, 500px" 
     alt="">
```

No `srcset`, você especifica o endereço da imagem e logo após a largurda dela em pixels (`1280w`). No atributo `sizes`, é indicado ao browser os breakpoints usando uma media querie e o tamanho que a imagem será exibida.
O tamanho `(max-width: 500px) 250px, 500px` diz ao browser "se a `viewport` for menor que 500px, a imagem terá 250px de largura. Se maior, a imagem será exibida com 500px de largura. O browser vai escolher qual daquelas imagens melhor se encaixa a essa situação.

Comment: 2 min e dou a resposta, eu to com a cabeça tão cheia que nem percebi :/

Comment: Editei a resposta por que existe um método alternativo que funciona em mais navegadores.